# $\text {let}\ p(z)=a_0+a_1z+\dotsb+a_{n-1}z^{n-1}+z^n,a_i\in\mathbb{C}.$ If $|p(z)|=1 \forall |z|=1$ is it true that $p(z)=z^n$?

Tags: complex-analysis

$\text {let}\ p(z)=a_0+a_1z+......+a_{n-1}z^{n-1}+z^n,a_i\in\mathbb{C}.$ if $|p(z)|=1 \forall |z|=1$ is it true that $p(z)=z^n$ for n=1,this is true.but is it also for higher value of n ???

Comment: only $a_{n-1}$ or $a_{n-1}z^{n-1}$? Otherwise please specify the pattern of the polynomial.

Comment: The answer is **yes**.  See these answers:  

[1]  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3408/characterizing-nonconstant-entire-functions-with-modulus-1-on-the-unit-circle
[2]  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/475344/rational-function-with-absolute-value-1-on-unit-circle